# Wordpress - How can I hide the_meta output if it is empty?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, meta

I've created a function and hook to insert some custom field information on some of my posts.

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

I have added some CSS formatting (box with background) for display. Problem: if I have a post without any custom fields defined it displays an empty box. How can I prevent it from outputting the empty  if there is nothing to display? All I can find is information on specific field types and and can't extrapolate from it. I'm definitely not a php boss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_post_custom()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) to get the custom fields as an array, and then do your output only if there are any custom fields in the array.

This should do the job, though it's not very elegant:

```
$has_custom = false;
foreach(get_post_custom_keys() as $k => $v) {
    $t = trim($v);
    if('_' != $t{0}) {
        $has_custom = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($has_custom) {
    the_meta();
}
```

Comment: Okay. I can look get_posts_custom() up. How would I tell it to only output if there are any custom fields defined? Or are you saying it would only display if the values are entered?

Comment: Posted some code that should do it. There may be a cleaner way but that should do the trick.

Comment: SQUEEEEE!!!! Perfect! Thank you SO SO much! You get a virtual warm chocolate chip cookie! I've been researching for hours and couldn't figure it out. THANK YOU!